# Pay higher than you normally do/would

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say you use electricity per day, and then the electric company increased the charge (payment) for electricity/per kilo watt of usage, and you say:

> Oh great! Because of this, I will pay higher than I normally **do**.

Or

> Oh great! Because of this, I will pay higher than I normally **would**.

I've seen someone used the sentence2 from a video to express this situation, but I am not sure why did they use "would" since it is not hypothetical (it's the truth to be exact). Whereas, the sentence1 sounds right to my ear...

Which of them should be used anyway?

Comment: Actually, "would" *is* signaling a hypothetical situation, specifically, the hypothetical when the complained about thing did not occur.

Comment: Idiomatically, it would nearly always be *I will pay **more***, not *I will pay higher*.

Comment: In fact, since the statement reflects a change from a past situation, I would probably say "Now I will pay more than I have done up to now".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The ***than-*** clause is effectively redundant anyway, but my guess is that [***more than I used to***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more+than+I+used+to%22) would be way more common than all variations on the theme of [***more than I have done up until now***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more+than+I+have+done+up+until+now%22) combined.

Comment: In a nutshell, my sentence should be "**oh great! Because of this, I will pay more than I used to from now on.** --is it ok now?

Answer (score 3):

The first example refers to the circumstances that normally occur.

The second example refers to a hypothetical situation that would occur now under different circumstances (i.e. if the electric company had not increased the rate).

The two sentences are subtly different, but express the same general concept.